# how to set X Y and hight width for scoll view

Tags: java, android

I have scroll-view and table-layout , row-table .

now i want to set X and Y margins and high and width for each one in programming code not xml .

note , I'm using Absolute layout for this activity .

this is my full code of activity :

public class ListActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);


AbsoluteLayout ff = (AbsoluteLayout)  this.findViewById(R.id.AbsoluteLayout1);


    TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    ScrollView myScrollView = new ScrollView(this);

            // adding scrollview to current layout 
    ff.addView(myScrollView);

           // adding TableLayout to current myScrollView
    myScrollView.addView(tl);


            /* not working
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(100 ,100);
    myScrollView.setLayoutParams(lp);*/


    myScrollView.setPadding(0, 210, 120, 0);

                /* not working 
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    myScrollView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);  */ 

    tr.addView(tv);

    tv.setText("gewgewg");

 tv.addView(tr);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with..

```
myScrollView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(500, 900));
myScrollView.addView(home_linear, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Fill this scroollview in your layout.For x,y you can see..

- [how to get specific position xy coordinates from Linear Layout android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017819/how-to-get-specific-position-xy-coordinates-from-linear-layout-android)
- [Android setting position of hortizontal scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507976/android-setting-position-of-hortizontal-scrollview)

Comment: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsoluteLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT has now been deprecated in favor of LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT