# Why is the post() method in Android attached to a specific View?

Tags: android, android-view

I'm wondering why the post() method is a specific to a View and not just a static method. It doesn't seem like the Runnable argument is closely tied to a specific view anyway.

I did find this other question which explains that (as of 4 years ago) the runnable will be run after the view has been drawn, but that doesn't quite answer my question.
[What event is fired after all views are fully drawn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947145/what-event-is-fired-after-all-views-are-fully-drawn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it decides which handler to post the event to based on a few different criteria.  Check the code at the AOSP.  If the view is attached to a window, it uses the one in the attach info.  If not, it uses the ViewRoot.getRunQueue and posts it there.  So there's a possibility of it posting to different handlers if, for example, you had a view in a different window like a Toast you were calling post on.  Thus the need for a non-static function.

Comment: "decides which handler to post the event to" - but the handlers are all ultimately called by the ui/main thread in a global run queue?